# Node.js: Pass data from a callback to the calling function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

Please, a simple example of how to pass data from a callback to the calling function in Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function callee (cb) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(null, { result: 'woohoo' })
  }, 100)
}

function caller () {
  callee(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
}

caller()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, God bless you.

Comment: You're very welcome. Have a good day! <3